# "used therein" vs "in use" vs "used" and "among" vs "between"

Tags: past-participles, between-among

I want to use the following sentence:

> I already explained 10 algorithms.

> As a result, the only difference (between / among) the algorithms is the blah-blah-blah model (used / in use / used therein).

Comment: It should be "the only difference is ..."

Comment: @DialFrost Thank you

Comment: There are many style guides that discuss the usage of "between" and "among". Have you done any research about that?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, I read many webpages about between and among. However, some websites said that 'between and among are the same only except that between can be used when objectds are no less than 2, but among can be used when objectds are no less than 3. But some websites said that 'between' and 'among' are exactly exchangeable. And some websites said that 'between' is followed by specified objects while 'among' is follwed by unspecified objects. I cannot guess which is correct. Also, I want to know which is correctd between used/in use/used therein.

Comment: @Danny_Kim That is useful information to include in your question, so that people understand what you already know and don't repeat things that you've already read.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Thank you. From now on, when I ask for something, I will put my knowledge obtained by that time. Thank you for your good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"between" is typically used when referring to two things, like "between a rock and a hard place," while "among" is used for a greater number. 10 is greater than 2, so you use "among".

"use" is present tense, "used" is past tense, and "used therein" is also past tense, but I would prefer not to use "therein" as it can be tricky to use in sentences, so stick with simplicity

> As a result, the only difference among the algorithms is the blah-blah-blah model *used/in use*.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to avoid using therein from now on.